# How to get the X axis value from HighChart on android on click event

Tags: android, kotlin, highcharts

what I am trying to do is click on one of the X axis labels and then go to another activity. I am using the highcharts library

this is how I call the graphic

```
        val options = GraphicDataResumeUtil().getOptionData(data, productiveSelected)
        multiAxesChart.options = options
        multiAxesChart.reload()
```

this is where I set the X values on my graphic class

```
fun getOptionData(
    listData: List<PoolHomeView>,
    variableSelectedCodes: List<ProductiveItemView>
): HIOptions {

    val chart = HIChart()
    chart.zoomType = "xy"
    options.chart = chart

    val title = HITitle()
    title.text = ""
    options.title = title

    val exporting = HIExporting()
    exporting.enabled = false
    options.exporting = exporting


    val listXAxis = mutableListOf<String>()

    for (i in listData.indices) {
        listXAxis.add("P " + listData[i].poolName)
    }

    val xaxis = HIXAxis()
    xaxis.categories = listXAxis.toCollection(ArrayList())
    xaxis.crosshair = HICrosshair()
    options.xAxis = ArrayList(Collections.singletonList(xaxis))

    val tooltip = HITooltip()
    tooltip.shared = true

    options.tooltip = tooltip

    return getGraphic2Axis(listData, variableSelectedCodes)
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the required `customEvents.js` plugin is not supported by the highcharts-android wrapper.

As an alternative, you can consider using a click on a series point.

```
val plotoptions = HIPlotOptions()
plotoptions.series = HISeries()
plotoptions.series.events = HIEvents()
plotoptions.series.point = HIPoint()
plotoptions.series.point.events = HIEvents()
plotoptions.series.point.events.click = HIFunction(
    HIConsumer { f: HIChartContext ->
    val t = Toast.makeText(
    this,
    "Clicked point [ " + f.getProperty("x") + ", " + f.getProperty("y") + " ]; category: " + f.getProperty(
    "category"
),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
)
t.show()
// start activity here with properties got in same way like in toast message
}, arrayOf("x", "y", "category")
)
options.plotOptions = plotoptions
```